# NullPointerException when doNothing() is called on Junit Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am writing a my unit test using Mockito but I am facing some error stubbing a method in the same class as my test class.

So basically, I am testing my service class MyService.class(**Subject being tested**) and this is how I am declaring my Mocks and @InjectMocks.

I am facing a null pointer whenever i hit the checkUserBackground() method when I am using doNothing() because the method returns void. I have also tried using verify() but I am getting error saying "Wanted but not invoked".

How do I get pass this error? Been stuck for 13 hours, appreciate some help thanks!

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@MockitoSettings(strictness = "Strictness.LENIENT")
class MyServiceTest {

@InjectMocks
private MyService myService;



@Test
void testCreateUser() {
  User user = new User();
  user.setAge(25);
  user.setName(Jack);


  Mockito.doNothing().when(myService).checkUserBackground(user.getName(), true); 
  assertEquals(myService.createUser().getName(), "Jack");
}
}
```

This is the actual Service class:

```
class MyService() {
 public static void createUser(User user) {

  checkUserBackground(user.getName(), true);      //Null Pointer here

}

public void checkUserBackground(String name, Boolean newUser){

 //some logic which doesnt matter
}
```

}

Comment: I think you confuse `@InjectMocks` with it's counter part(s) `@Mock`/-`Bean`!? MyService is null?(!)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full exception message and stacktrace. It looks like you are calling the static method `MyService.createUser()`, but there is no such call in your code/unit test.

Comment: Your service class does not compile, and I'm reasonably sure those methods do not need to be static

Comment: Your methods are static. You can't mock static methods with Mockito.

Comment: updated the question to remove the static, which is still causing Null Pointer

Comment: Most important question, you must clarify: is `MyService` "subject under test" ..(x)or is it a mock ?

Comment: @xerx593 updated the question. Yes MyService.class is the class being tested. Hence, i showed MyServiceTest.class. Lol.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. What is `mockService`?

Comment: @tgdavies updated the question, it should be myService. Basically I just want to mock the response of another method in the same test class. Having issues with NullPointer

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full stack trace.

Comment: ..then why are you trying to mock it, when it is class under Test?

Answer (score 0):

Annotation `@InjectMock` is for dependency injection - its real class bean. But later in method you try mock method of injected bean.
In your case will be enougth when you add method instead annotation:

```
@Before
public void init() {
    myService = Mockito.mock(MyService.class)
}
```